React/Vite won't load env.local
I am trying to configure my vite/React app so that we can put the server address in an environment variable.
I am trying to store the server address in env.local and loading it with loadEnv but I can't get the environment variables to load.
If I hard code my server address it works fine.
My env.local file just contains
VITE_API_URL=http://120.0.0.1:8080

Here is my vite.config.ts:


import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';
import { TanStackRouterVite } from '@tanstack/router-vite-plugin';
import { loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '');

  if (!env.VITE_API_URL) {
    throw new Error(`VITE_API_URL is not defined <${mode}> ${JSON.stringify(env)}`);
  }

  return {
    plugins: [TanStackRouterVite(), react()],
    base: '/app/',
    server: {
      proxy: {
        // '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', <<-- this works
        '/api': env.VITE_API_URL,
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      },
    },
    build: {
      sourcemap: true,
      outDir: 'build',
    },
  };
});



The exception throws. If I remove the exception my calls to the back end won't work.

"The exception throws" - Which exception? You haven't added any in the question. Please [edit] and add the full error/exception as text inside it.

this is answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79203480/any-mention-of-env-brakes-vite-app-on-production

Place your .env.local file in the root directory of your project, at the same level as your vite.config.ts file

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks Sameer. The file is where it should be.
